# What is the difference between liquibase diff and diffChangeLog ? How to run the maven command for diffChangeLog?

Tags: spring, jpa, liquibase

I am new to Liquibase and I learned that the two modes `diff` and `diffChangeLog` uses the target and base (reference) databases in opposite direction.

```
Using "diff" will show the difference going from 'base (reference)' -> 'target' which makes sense.
While "diffChangeLog" outputs the difference going from 'target' to 'base (reference)'.
```

I ran the maven goal `liquibase:diffChangeLog` , but I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'diffChangeLog' in plugin 
org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.5.1 among available goals dropAll, 
rollback, clearCheckSums, updateTestingRollback, changelogSync, updateSQL, 
migrateSQL, generateChangeLog, dbDoc, status, listLocks, changelogSyncSQL, 
releaseLocks, migrate, tag, diff, rollbackSQL, futureRollbackSQL, update, 
help -> [Help 1]
```

What did I do wrong? How can I run `liquibase:diffChangeLog` as a maven ?

Answer (score 1):

`diff` (`liquibase:diff`) is the `maven goal` used to find the difference between the db states.

`diffChangeLog` is the argument to the `command line` for doing the `Liquibase` operation using an `command line tool`. There is no maven goal called `liquibase:diffChangeLog`

Internally the code looks like this

```
    if ("diff".equalsIgnoreCase(this.command)) {
    CommandLineUtils.doDiff(createReferenceDatabaseFromCommandParams(this.commandParams, fileOpener), database, StringUtils.trimToNull(this.diffTypes), finalSchemaComparisons);
  }
  else if ("diffChangeLog".equalsIgnoreCase(this.command)) {
    CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(this.changeLogFile, createReferenceDatabaseFromCommandParams(this.commandParams, fileOpener), database, diffOutputControl, StringUtils.trimToNull(this.diffTypes), finalSchemaComparisons);
  }
```